Sum of comparisons and exchange between two sorting methods and their comparison (shell and quicksort)
I'm trying to make a code that counts Shell and Merge comparisons and swaps, making a sum between the sum of the comps and swaps. The vectors are a subArray, such that, given: 4 (line break here) 3 6 5 2 I will have [3] [3 6] [3 6 5] [3 6 5 2]. However, for some reason my code is not working as expected, I will leave a test case and what the answer should be, my suspicion is that I am not generating the subArrays correctly but I couldn't think of how to fix it.
Test case:
15
1 9 3 0 3 9 8 6 8 4 1 0 0 1 2
Expected Output:
-SSSSSSSSSSQSSS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int comp;
    int swap;
} count;

void shell(int v[], int n, count *s) {
    int gap = 1;
    while (gap <= n) {
        gap *= 2;
    }
    gap = gap / 2 - 1;
    while (gap > 0) {
        for (int i = gap; i < n; i++) {
            int x = v[i];
            int j = i - gap;
            s->comp++; 
            while (j >= 0 && v[j] > x) {
                v[j + gap] = v[j];
                s->swap++;
                j -= gap;
                s->comp++; 
            }
            v[j + gap] = x;
        }
        gap /= 2;
    }
}

void quick(int v[], int f, int l, count *q) {
    if (f >= l) {
        return;
    }
    int m = (l + f) / 2;
    int pivot = v[m];
    int i = f;
    int j = l;

    while (1) {
        while (i <= l && v[i] < pivot) {
            q->comp++; 
            i++;
        }
        if (i >= j) {
            break;
        }
        while (j >= f && v[j] > pivot) {
            q->comp++; 
            j--;
        }
        if (i >= j) {
            break;
        }
        int aux = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = aux;
        q->swap++; 
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    quick(v, f, j, q);
    quick(v, j + 1, l, q);
}


int* gSubV(int V[], int size) {
    int *subv = (int*) malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        subv[i] = V[i]; 
    }
    return subv;
}

void freesubv(int **subv, int N) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        free(subv[i]);
    }
    free(subv);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *V = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &V[i]);  
    }

    count q = {0, 0};
    count s = {0, 0};
    int **subv = (int**) malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    int **subv2 = (int**) malloc(n * sizeof(int*));


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        subv[i] = gSubV(V, i + 1);
        subv2[i] = gSubV(V, i + 1);

        
        shell(subv[i], i + 1, &s); 
        quick(subv2[i], 0, i, &q);

        int totalq = q.comp + q.swap;
        int totals = s.comp + s.swap;

        if (totalq > totals) {
            printf("S ");
        } else if (totalq < totals) {
            printf("Q ");
        } else {
            printf("- ");
        }

        q.comp = 0;
        q.swap = 0;
        s.comp = 0;
        s.swap = 0;

    }

    freesubv(subv, n);
    freesubv(subv2, n);
    free(V);

    return 0;
}


void shell(int v[], int n) {

    int gap = 1;

    while(gap <= n) {

        gap *= 2;

    }

    gap = gap / 2 - 1;

    while(gap > 0) {

            for (int i = gap; i < n; i++){

                int x = v[i];

                int j = i - gap;

                while(j >= 0 && v[j] > x) {

                    v[j + gap] = v[j];

                    j -= gap;

                }

                v[j + gap] = x;

            }

        gap /= 2;

    }

}

void quick(int v[], int f, int l) {

        if (f >= l) {

                return;

        }

        int m = (l + f)/2;

        int pivot = v[m];

        int i = f;

        int j = l;

        while(1) {

                while(v[i] < pivot) {

                        i++;

                }

                while(v[j] > pivot) {

                        j--;

                }

                if (i >= j) {

                        break;

                }

                int aux = v[i];

                v[i] = v[j];

                v[j] = aux;

                i++;

                j--;

        }

        quick(v, f, j);

        quick(v, j+1, l);

}


When you used a debugger, what was the first thing it did that you didn't expect?

When i debugged i saw that the subArray was correct, but i am not sure if the counts are in the correct place

freesubv was a translate error, consider it as freeSubV

There are different variants of both shell sort and merge sort. Shell sort can have different gap sequences, merge sort can split odd arrays in partitions with either the left or the right one being shorter, ...etc. The total number of comparisons/swaps depends on such choices. How do you know you have implemented the right variant? Also, you speak in the first paragraph of your question of Merge (sort?), but have a function that is doing quick sort...

@trincot this is an class assignment, the teacher gave the code of the shell and quick with the gap he wanted to

So this is the teacher's code? What code are you asking about?

@trincot This is my code, the teacher only gave the sorting method code (quick and shell function)  and we had to do the rest and change it as needed, such as generating a subArray as well as counting exchanges and comparisons.

Please provide the code that was given to you, and your version separately. It is not clear to me what exactly is your work in this code.

@trincot done, just added the codes provided to me
